# Transactional Emails - Default Styling and Variables in Magento 1.9

Tags: html, magento, magento-1.9, transactional-email

I'm looking for 2 specific variables.

Wishlist - The var_message variable has some styling to it that im trying to edit.

Abandoned Carts - pulls on this extension URL : connector/email/basket/code/secret/quote_id/*****

And im unable to find the location of the file that is accessed by that URL or command.

Any assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Also if someone could tell me how i might trace the locations of these things without "Just knowing" that would be grand too.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct variable name is `message` (not var_message)

variable message is populated in controller `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController`
inside method `sendAction`

here it is:

```
        $emailModel = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $sharingCode = $wishlist->getSharingCode();
        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $emailModel->sendTransactional(
                Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_template'),
                Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_identity'),
                $email,
                null,
                array(
                    'customer'       => $customer,
                    'salable'        => $wishlist->isSalable() ? 'yes' : '',
                    'items'          => $wishlistBlock,
                    'addAllLink'     => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/allcart', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'viewOnSiteLink' => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'message'        => $message
                )
            );
        }

        $wishlist->setShared(1);
        $wishlist->save();
```

and the actual content of the message comes from a form input and gets fetched over here:

```
$message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars((string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('message')));
```

there is no actual styling or css assigned to it. In fact most of styles are defined `inline` in email templates

Comment: for the sake of completeness, here is the template of the wishlist share form, where message meant to be entered: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml

Comment: Thanks, that helps, the email has no inline styling though yet the message appears to have a yellow background. Where would it be acquiring that styling from if it is not getting it from the email inline or the function itself?

Comment: check if you have a modified transactional template for wishlist. System->Transactional Emails->"Share Wishlist". If not the default one is located at app/locale/en_US/template/email/wishlist_share.html. Default template also includes this css file skin/frontend/base/default/css/email-inline.css